# I can't get nulls to crash my C# program?

Tags: c#, crash, null

Ok so I have this weird problem, and I've searched Google many times for an answer but to no avail...  Anyways I have this problem where I can't seem to get my program(s) to show me error messages when I want. This has happened on many occasions and eventually figure out that its a variable that's null, but for some reason no error was thrown?

Here's an example of one I just had.

Person clicks a button to show a new form called debug.

```
Debug debug = new Debug();
debug.Show(this);
```

And this was in my debug form.

```
public new void Show(IWin32Window owner)
{
    base.Show(owner);
    Parent.Move += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Location = new Point(Parent.Location.X + Parent.Width, Parent.Location.Y);
    });
}
```

Long story short, the code didn't work because Parent was null but it never even hinted that was the problem.

I'm sure there some explanation but I have yet to find one in my Google searches...

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Parent` class please?

Comment: Did you debug and single step the line starting with Parent.Move? 
If Parent is null it will throw an exception and you can see where it ends up

Comment: No, if you have an variable that is a reference to an object, and that reference is `null`, then doing anything on that reference will result in an error. If you want us to help you then you'll need to show code that produces something tangible.

Comment: Parent was null inside `Show`  or inside your event handler? Dou you have `[STATHread]` set on your starting point?

Comment: Well I also have put if(Parent == null) { MessageBox.Show("Parent null"); } in there(after trying to figure out why my code wasn't working). And it would show the message, but once it got to Parent.Move anything after that the code never executes, and I'm not informed of any errors, I have my program set to debug mode, I would think it would stop it once it hit Parent.Move +=...

Comment: Is it possible that your entire program is wrapped in a try{} catch{} or you are using one of the UncaughtException events that are available on various classes?

Comment: I have actually since deleted the code and got it working, but it just boggles my mind how that wouldn't throw a null error lol. Also the Parent class I thought was suppose to be the form that called debug.Show(this) - I was wrong so I came up with a different method that works but still would be nice to get it to throw an error so I don't waste time lol.

Comment: You can also try the following in Visual Studio:
 1. Debug > Exceptions
 2. Expand the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" entry
 3. Expand the "System" entry
 4. Click the checkbox for System.NullReferenceException
 5. Click OK
 6. Run your application with the debugger attached.
It will now cause the debugger to break whenever a NullReferenceException is thrown.

Comment: @Steve TY, it works now! lol that could have saved me like 30 mins! Genius!

Comment: @Skint007 I've made my comment into an answer seeing as it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try the following in Visual Studio:

1. Debug > Exceptions
2. Expand the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" entry
3. Expand the "System" entry
4. Click the checkbox for System.NullReferenceException
5. Click OK
6. Run your application with the debugger attached.

It will now cause the debugger to break whenever a NullReferenceException is thrown.

I would guess that either your Application is wrapped in a try{} catch{} or, somewhere at the base of the callstack that results in debug.Show() being called, the code is wrapped in a try{} catch{}